# How to remove duplicate/inverted rows from INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am using SQL to pull from a table, I am also using an INNER JOIN to select to rows with linking values/columns, and appending them into one big row.

Table below:

```
   | name    |   value    |   num |
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |
   | James   |   JEU836   |   4   |
```

I am now joining these two rows, into one row using this SQL:

```
SELECT  a.name, a.value, a.num, b.name, b.value, b.num
FROM MY_TABLE a
INNER JOIN MY_TABLE b ON a.name = b.name //Inner joining where the name is the same
WHERE a.value <> b.value // where the values are NO the same
```

Result:

```
   | a.name  |   a.value  | a.num | b.name  |   b.value  | b.num |
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |  James  |   JEU836   |   4   |
   | James   |   JEU836   |   4   |  James  |   HEX124   |   1   |
```

As you can see in the result, this is working, but it's returning every possible result, I want to only return one of these rows, as its duplicated/inverted them almost.

Maybe by returning only the first row WHERE a.name is a duplicate?

Desired Result:

```
   | a.name  |   a.value  | a.num | b.name  |   b.value  | b.num |
   | James   |   HEX124   |   1   |  James  |   JEU836   |   4   |
```

Thank you

Comment: You must guarantee strictly 2 duplicates by `name`. Or define the output more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change:

```
a.value <> b.value
```

to:

```
a.value < b.value
```

I would put the condition in the `ON` clause, like this:

```
SELECT a.name, a.value, a.num, b.name, b.value, b.num
FROM MY_TABLE a INNER JOIN
     MY_TABLE b
     ON a.name = b.name AND a.value < b.value;
```